# Delete vs Rollback Strategy - ETL Load

Tags: sql-server, etl, sql-server-2016

I am loading data to table in the following manner:

```
DECLARE @srcRc INT;
DECLARE @dstRc INT;

SET @srcRc = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A )

INSERT  INTO t
        (Col1
        ,Col2
        ,Col3
        )
        SELECT  A.Col1
               ,A.Col2
               ,B.Col3
        FROM    A
                JOIN B
                    ON A.Id = B.Id;

SET @dstRc = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Now I am comparing the variables `@srcRc` and `@dstRc`. The `ROWCOUNT` must be the same. If it is not, the inserted rows need to be deleted.

Q1: What would be the best strategy to rollback the inserted rows?

I have couple of ideas:

1) Run the load in transaction and rollback if the rowcount does not match.
2) Add flag column (bit) to the destination table called `toBeDeleted`, run the load and if the rowcount does not match, update the `toBeDeleted` column with `1` value to flag it as candidate for deletion. Then delete in batch mode (while-loop). 
 Or do not delete them, but always exclude deletion candidates from query when working with `t` table.
3) Before inserting the rows, compare the the rowcount first. If it does not match, don't start the load.

```
DECLARE @srcRc INT;
DECLARE @dstRc INT;
SET @srcRc = ( SELECT   COUNT(1) FROM A );
SET @dstRc = ( SELECT   COUNT(1) FROM A JOIN B ON A.Id = B.Id );
```

Q2: What would be better solution for higher amount of rows, let's say 10-100 mil.?
Q3: Or is there any better strategy for similar case?

Answer (score 0):

OK, Assuming :

You need the roll back to work at some later date when the content of tables A and B may have changed

There may also be other rows in T which you don't want to delete as part of the rollback.

Then you MUST keep a list of the rows you inserted, as you are unable to reliably regenerate that list from A and B and you cant just delete everything from T

You could do this in two ways

- Change your import, so that it first inserts the rows to an import table, keep the import table hanging around until you are sure you don't need it anymore.
- Add an extra column to T [importId] into which you put a uniquely identifying value

Obviously the first strategy uses a lot more disc space. So the longer your keep the data and the more data there is, the better the extra column looks.

Another option, would be to generate the list of imported data separately and have your transaction sql be a bulk insert with all the data hard coded into the sql.

This works well for small lists, initial setup data and the like.

---

Edit:

from your comments it sounds like you don't want a roll back per-se. But the best way to apply business logic around the import process.

In this case your 3rd answer is the best. Don't do the import when you know the source data is incorrect.

Comment: I need to rollback only the "current" load, not the history. So usually I load day by day. Today I Am loading date N, tomorrow N+1. So only the current batch's rowcount is checked.
And if the rowcount does not match, all from the current load needs to be erased, not just some of the rows.

Comment: the trouble with those scenarios is its not really a rollback unless you undo whatever it was you did. Anything relying on a simple row count can go wrong. eg you duplicate row x and skip row y. your row counts will match

Comment: That"s true but that case has never happened and I consider it to be very rare.

Comment: a rollback is for those rare times when things go wrong